# How to avoid 0 OverVector[F] to be evaluated as 0?

Tags: evaluation, symbolic, linear-algebra, vector

I am fairly new in *Mathematica* and I am trying to work with scalars and vectors. I decided to denote vectors using `OverVector` (as example, `OverVector[F]`stands for the force). Any scalar is denoted by a symbol.

When an expression has a multiplication between scalar and vector, the expected outcome should be *nullVector*, but *Mathematica* evaluated this as zero. (I have been using Notation package and

```
Notation[OverVector[0]\[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] nullVector]
```

*nullVector* stands for the zero vector)

How I can prevent *Mathematica* to evaluate `Times[OverVector[F],0]` as zero?

In other words. I need *Mathematica* evaluates the multiplication between vector and zero as the zero vector (nullVector) not as zero. How I can get this?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

Using `TagSetDelayed` allows this definition to be associated with `OverVector` instead of `Times`:

```
OverVector /: Times[OverVector[_], 0] := nullVector
```

Comment: Many thanks @Marius. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

One way is

```
Unprotect[Times];
Times[OverVector[_],0] = nullVector
Protect[Times];
```

though generally it's not a good idea to redefine built-in commands.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, I think too it's not a good practice to redefine built-in commands. I´m cheking the code with the @Marius´s idea.